# Zend_Db and unbuffered queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, unbuffered-queries

I have a long running query which I try to fetch via an unbuffered pdo-statement (see code next).
But when I 'execute' the query unbuffered, or I do a 'fetchAll', the timings (also see under) don't really change much...
What I thought is that unbuffered just executes the query and give me a cursor?

The get_db function returns a Zend_Db object.

```
  l('Start 1');

  $sql = get_db('ATO')->select()
                       ... Big query...
                       ->assemble();

  l('Assembled');

  get_db('APNS')->query($sql)->fetchAll();

  l('All fetched... Going again!');

  $PDOStatement = get_db('ATO')->getConnection()
                                ->prepare($sql,
                          array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false));

  l('prepared');

  if ( $PDOStatement->execute() === false ) {
    l(':(');
    exit(1);
  }

  l('fetching');

  while ( ($PDOrow = $PDOStatement->fetch()) !== false ) {
  }

  l ('all done');

  function l($t) {
    static $start = null;
    if ( $start === null ) {
      $start = microtime(true);
    }
    echo sprintf("[%0.5f] %s\n", microtime(true) - $start, $t);
  }
```

And the timings:

```
[0.00000] Start 1
[0.02262] Assembled
[214.69091] All fetched... Going again!
[214.69105] prepared
[417.01584] fetching
[420.55217] all done
```

As you can see there is nearly no difference in fetching all and the unbuffered variant.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong because you try to use unbuffered queries to speed up.

1. Buffered queries fetch all result to PHP memory.
2. With unbuffered result lies on server until it would be fetched.

Every way has own advantages and disadvantages but it weakly related to time.

Read manual [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

Comment: Actually it is strongly related to time in this case. As when the data is fetched into PHP it uses a lot of memory. If I keep it on the server the data isn't fetched at once, so no additional memory needs to be allocated. - This was resulting in about 50s speed increase for this script!

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem, I wrote "weakly related to time". I think that you looking optimization in wrong place. Try to execute your sql in mysql client to measure time. Oh, just remember... prepared statement waste some time too... But do not use it info for your optimization.

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem, "This was resulting in about 50s speed increase for this script!" so update your post with new measuring.

Comment: post was done at 2012-07-03... We're nearly 1 year further :). I don't have access to that code anymore mate ;)